# Eclipse not allowing to modify files without checkout in ClearCase

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase-ucm

I am using ClearCase plugin for Eclipse.

Whenever I am trying to modify any files in eclipse, it is asking me to checkout the file and then modify.

I want to modify the file offline and then checkout by hijacking and after this checkin the required changes.

How can I do this using the ClearCase plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

The problem was : "Connect to rational ClearCase" was selected. This was not allowing me to modify the file without checkout of the file.

When I deselect the "Connect to rational ClearCase", the view is no more connected to the ClearCase repository and is allowing me  to make changes.

After making the changes when I select the "Connect to rational ClearCase" option, the decorator mark shows that file has been hijacked.

Thanks!

Comment: @VonC - When "Connect to rational ClearCase" is selected, Eclipse is not allowing to modify the file without checkout.

Comment: Even if the file is already read-write (and not just read-only)?

Comment: Yes even if the file is in read-write mode, still it is not allowing to modify the files. When "Connect to rational ClearCase" is selected, eclipse tries to modify the files directly in the repository. This is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make all file writable within your snapshot view.
Then Eclipse won't bother you when you want to modify one.

Once you are ready to checkin, as explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741062/6309), you will have first to checkout all the files you modified, and then check them in.
(I recommend not using Eclipse for this step, but rather a [recursive checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119595/6309), and a [recursive checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974016/6309))