# Why does the requirejs optimizer need write permissions on my source files? Can this be worked around?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, clearcase, r.js

I'm working on optimizing a project that we have begun to convert to AMD syntax, and I've been running into some issues.

Our version control tool, Clearcase, leaves files as read-only in the file system when they are not checked out.  When I've attempted to use `node r.js` to optimize the project, I've found that that has caused problems.  Specifically it seems that it tries to gain write access to the files that I've defined as modules to optimize in my build file.

My build file looks something like this:

```
{
   baseUrl: "../",
   mainConfigFile: "./config.js",
   appDir: ".../../build/",
   dir: "../",
   modules: [{
      name:"file1"
   }]
}
```

When I leave file1.js checked in, I see an error message

```
Error: EACCES permission denied '.../file1.js' 
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
```

When I check it out and gain write permissions it works without a problem.  I've tested this and it consistently seems that it needs write permissions to work.

I don't understand this, since these files shouldn't be written to at all, they only need to be read. Is there a workaround for this? Have I done something wrong?

I'm also curious if there's a reason for this limitation (if its not simply my mistake), or if it was just something that was overlooked that is not a problem for most people.  I've been unable to find other people who've had this issue, so I may be in a relative unique situation (there's admittedly probably not a huge overlap of people using clearcase and Node.js)

Comment: Could you cut and paste the actual build file you pass to ``r.js`` into your question? What you currently have here is not syntactically correct.

Comment: @Louis-DominiqueDubeau this is essentially the same file.  I just changed the names.  I apparently accidentally removed the commas when I did.  The build file isn't really the issue anyway.  It works just fine when there is write permissions on the files.

Comment: I've just made the modules of my 50-module application read-only, ran ``r.js`` but did not get an error. So the problem is not with ``r.js`` or the permissions on the input files (i.e. ``r.js`` is not trying to open its input files for writing) but with the build configuration you give to ``r.js``. Without having the real paths that you are using, it is impossible for me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without addressing the node.js aspect, you could try and see what happens if you make those files [hijacked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741062/6309).

That assumes you are using a ClearCase snapshot view, in which you can control the write attribute.
But you even can [do that with a dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7799307/6309).